# Получить svg с изогнутым текстом в виде арки

Tags: svg, изображения

Задача получить изогнутый текст. Идеально, если с возможностью изменения цвета, шрифта, размера шрифта.

Вот пример:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 6):

> Идеально, если с возможностью изменения цвета, шрифта, размера шрифта.

Используйте [textPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/textPath)

Это команда для размещения текста вдоль траектории.

Остаётся только создать траекторию в форме арки в векторном редакторе.

```css
.container {
 width:50vw;
 height:50vh;
 }
 #txt {
 fill:#005E46;
 font-size:84px;
 font-family:sans-serif;
 font-weight:bold;
 letter-spacing:1px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       viewBox="0 10 656 544"  >  

   <path id="top" fill="none" d="m 86.959108,536.92194 c 0,0 -10.133315,-158.67922 2.022305,-236.60967 4.731862,-30.33627 12.118517,-61.28378 27.301117,-87.97026 15.93166,-28.00312 39.52587,-51.70293 64.71375,-71.79182 23.23934,-18.53481 49.18226,-35.65231 77.85874,-43.479558 41.30634,-11.274567 86.74257,-12.863251 128.41636,-3.033457 31.55069,7.442015 59.98355,26.093615 85.94795,45.501855 16.60888,12.41505 30.85349,28.04167 43.47955,44.49071 14.07865,18.34144 27.2555,38.01449 35.39034,59.65799 8.44276,22.46274 10.89155,46.88973 13.14498,70.78067 7.08982,75.16651 1.01115,226.49814 1.01115,226.49814" />

<text id="txt"  dy="-2px" dx="0">
  <textPath  xlink:href="#top"   startOffset="-0.5%"> LEARN MORE ABOUT  LIBEO  </textPath> 
 </text> 
</svg>  
</div>
```

В CSS можно установить нужные вам атрибуты шрифта.

Положение первой буквы устанавливается с помощью `startOffset`

Comment: А есть ли возможность отцентрировать на пути строку, то есть вне зависимости от размера шрифта чтобы середина строки совпадала с серединой пути? Еще лучше, чтобы размер шрифта подгонялся под длину пути так, чтобы текст располагался по всей длине этого пути. И если через JS, то как можно получить длину текста и подогнать размер под длину кривой?

Comment: @GivNeyt Если ответ вам был полезен, не забудьте отметить его решением

Answer (score 3):

В комментарии @Leonid
задал новые вопросы, поэтому новый ответ

> А есть ли возможность отцентрировать на пути строку, то есть вне
> зависимости от размера шрифта чтобы середина строки совпадала с
> серединой пути?

- При `startOffset="0"` первый символ слова будет совпадать с началом
  линии
- При `startOffset="50%"` первый символ слова будет совпадать с
  серединой линии
- `text-anchor:middle;` позиционирует фразу по середине относительно
  заданной точки. Этой заданной точкой является середина кривой,
  заданная атрибутом `startOffset="50%"`

Таким образом используя эти два атрибута вместе получаем:
**Фраза расположена симметрично по своей длине относительно середины кривой**

параметр `dy="-10"` служит для обеспечения зазора между кривой и текстом

**font-size:84px;**

```css
.container {
 width:50vw;
 height:50vh;
 }
 #txt {
 fill:#005E46;
 font-size:84px;
 font-family:sans-serif;
 font-weight:bold;
 letter-spacing:1;
text-anchor:middle;
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       viewBox="0 10 656 544"  >  

   <path id="top" fill="none" stroke="red" d="m 86.959108,536.92194 c 0,0 -10.133315,-158.67922 2.022305,-236.60967 4.731862,-30.33627 12.118517,-61.28378 27.301117,-87.97026 15.93166,-28.00312 39.52587,-51.70293 64.71375,-71.79182 23.23934,-18.53481 49.18226,-35.65231 77.85874,-43.479558 41.30634,-11.274567 86.74257,-12.863251 128.41636,-3.033457 31.55069,7.442015 59.98355,26.093615 85.94795,45.501855 16.60888,12.41505 30.85349,28.04167 43.47955,44.49071 14.07865,18.34144 27.2555,38.01449 35.39034,59.65799 8.44276,22.46274 10.89155,46.88973 13.14498,70.78067 7.08982,75.16651 1.01115,226.49814 1.01115,226.49814" />

<text id="txt"  dy="-10px" dx="0">
  <textPath  xlink:href="#top"   startOffset="50%"> LEARN MORE ABOUT  </textPath> 
 </text> 
</svg>  
</div>
```

Шрифт уменьшаем `font-size:32px;`

```css
.container {
 width:50vw;
 height:50vh;
 }
 #txt {
 fill:#005E46;
 font-size:32px;
 font-family:sans-serif;
 font-weight:bold;
 letter-spacing:1;
text-anchor:middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       viewBox="0 10 656 544"  >  

   <path id="top" fill="none" stroke="red" d="m 86.959108,536.92194 c 0,0 -10.133315,-158.67922 2.022305,-236.60967 4.731862,-30.33627 12.118517,-61.28378 27.301117,-87.97026 15.93166,-28.00312 39.52587,-51.70293 64.71375,-71.79182 23.23934,-18.53481 49.18226,-35.65231 77.85874,-43.479558 41.30634,-11.274567 86.74257,-12.863251 128.41636,-3.033457 31.55069,7.442015 59.98355,26.093615 85.94795,45.501855 16.60888,12.41505 30.85349,28.04167 43.47955,44.49071 14.07865,18.34144 27.2555,38.01449 35.39034,59.65799 8.44276,22.46274 10.89155,46.88973 13.14498,70.78067 7.08982,75.16651 1.01115,226.49814 1.01115,226.49814" />

<text id="txt"  dy="-10px" dx="0">
  <textPath  xlink:href="#top"   startOffset="50%"> LEARN MORE ABOUT  </textPath> 
 </text> 
</svg>  
</div>
```